# Вывести возраста и на основе этого возраста вычислить в каком году родился пользователь

Tags: python

```
user_name = input('Name:')
print(' Welcome dear,'+ user_name)
user_age = input('Age:')
print(user_age)
from datetime import date
```

Понимаю что от сегодняшней даты нужно отнять user_age, но не понимаю как прописать
Спасибо!

Comment: `date.today().year - user_age`

Comment: `date.today().year - int(user_age)`

Comment: import datetime
date_ = datetime.date.today().year - int(user_age)
print(date_)

Решил, спасибо)

Comment: @RostislavPopov Если Вы нашли решение, то можете ответить на собственный вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime 
date_ = datetime.date.today().year - int(user_age) 
print(date_)
```